# Android: ClassNotFoundException when including SimpleXML converter for Retrofit2

Tags: java, android, classnotfoundexception, retrofit2, simple-framework

Im using Retrofit2 to make calls to different APIs, up until now I've only called on REST APIs but now I needed a SOAP API call. It has worked as it should up until I add a dependency to

```
compile 'compile('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.0.2') {
    compile.exclude module: 'stax'
    compile.exclude module: 'stax-api'
    compile.exclude module: 'xpp3'
}
```

where it kind of freaks out on me. Im getting the following error when the call is made, Im using callbacks for the responses and in the failure clause I get this:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
"user_font_size_normal" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data
/app/com.my.app.debug-2.apk", zip file "/data/data/com.my.app.debug
/code_cache/secondary-dexes/com.my.app.debug-
2.apk.classes2.zip"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib
/com.my.app.debug-2, /system/lib]]
```

I have multiDex enabled. If I remove the compile.exludes I think there's some ProGuard issue because it won't compile at all then. Im using gsonconverter since before and using retrofit 2.0.2.

Any ideas?
Best regards,
Christopher

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you're still having this issue, but I just ran into it and I just had to change my gradle dependency to look like this.

```
compile('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.1.0', {
    exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
    exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
    exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax'
})
```

Hope that helps.